# Spring boot @onetomany error memory leak even if I put @JsonIgnore

Tags: java, spring-boot, one-to-many

In Spring Boot, I have three classes `User`, `Post` and `Comment`. `User` is one to many with `Post` and `Post` is one to many with `Comment`. I want retrieve object `Post` with set of `Comment`s and the `User` who commented. But when I do `User @onetomany` with `Comment` it's giving me an error "memory leak" even if I add `@JsonIgnore`.

```
public class UserInfo {
        private Long id;
        private String userName;
        private double phoneNo;
        private double idCard;
        
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userInfo", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Set <Post> post = new HashSet<>() ;
        
        public void setPost(Set<Post> post) {
            this.post = post;
        }

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "comment_id")
        @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
        private Comment comment;

        public int getCommentId(){
            return comment.getId();
        }
        
        @JsonIgnore
        public Post getComment() {
            return comment;
        }

        @JsonIgnore
        public void setComment(Comment comment) {
            this.comment = comment;
        }
}

public class Post extends DateGen {
        private int id;
        private String title;
        private String discription;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "userInfo_id")
        @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
        private UserInfo userInfo;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Set <Comment> comment  = new HashSet<>() ;
        
        public void setComment(Set<Comment> comment) {
            this.comment = comment;
        }

        public Long getUserInfo_id(){
            return userInfo.getId();
        }
        
        @JsonIgnore
        public UserInfo getUserInfo() {
            return userInfo;
        }
}

public class Comment  extends DateGen {
        private int id;
        private String comment;
        
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
        @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
        private Post post;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "comment", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Set <UserInfo> userInfo  = new HashSet<>() ;
        
        public void setComment(Set<UserInfo> userInfo) {
            this.userInfo = userInfo;
        }
        
        public int getPostId(){
            return post.getId();
        }
        
        @JsonIgnore
        public Post getPost() {
            return postRequest;
        }

        @JsonIgnore
        public void setPost(Post post) {
            this.post = post;
        }
}
```

Comment: Put @JsonIgnore on the field instead of on getter.